# Fastest way to dump all blobs in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, blob

I'm trying to dump all blobs in a large table to the file system. The table is like:

```
Name                   Null?    Type          
---------------------- -------- ------------- 
ID                     NOT NULL NUMBER(19)    
FILENAME               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(256) 
OFFSET_BLOB                     BLOB
```

I need to dump all `OFFSET_BLOB`s to the file system in files named `[filename].offsets`.

My current approach is to create a stored procedure that iterates through all of the rows and then uses `UTL_FILE.put_raw()` to write the data to the file. It's working fine, but the table has over 250 million rows and the current estimation is to take 5 days to complete. I tried to add parallel hints on the query with /*+ FULL PARALLEL(10) */ but it doesn't improve anything :(.

Does any of you have a better approach to drastically reduce the extract time to hours instead of days? Thank you!

Comment: There does not seem to be a much better solution. Just let it slug away and take however long it takes.  On the positive side since you are not updating tables it will not interfere with other database processing, other than taking cpu cycles and io activity.  But perhaps you need to take a realistic look; do you really want to **create 250million files** on the file system?  Or put **250million unidentified blobs in 1file**?

Comment: Parallel query isn't going to help because it is the not the *query* that is slow - it is the writing of the blobs.  Check out dbms_parallel_execute which will let you run multiple exports concurrently.